# LocationClient cannot resolved symbol in android studio?

Tags: android

Below is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domore.googlelocationdemo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Here,Is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.domore.googlelocationdemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    LocationClien
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

What will i need to do?
Please any one help me to solve out this error?

I was used a LocationRequest class but which parameter i need to set LocationRequeset class constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the compiled sdk version as LocationClient is deprecated in  API23 so you can use new libraries

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient and 
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.
```

Comment: you mean i will use LocationRequest insted of LocationClient?